# hide a specific Sharepoint form field if the user is not the creator of the record

Tags: column, formatting, conditional, hidden, hide-elements

I would like to hide a specific Sharepoint form field if the user is not the creator of the record.
I'm trying to use conditional formatting without success.
Some one can help me?

Thank in advance

Comment: What is your SharePoint version?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are working on SharePoint Online. OOB there is no way to hide a specific form field based on whether the user is the creator or not.